# Adding an item to jList

Tags: java, jlist

I have searched around the internet, and have tried a lot of different solutions, but each one led to a different problem. Here is the code:

```
String path = "path usually goes here"; 
File folder = new File(path);
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (;this.filen < listOfFiles.length; filen++) {
    File lof = new File("path and stuff/Assignment" + filen + ".txt");

    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream(lof)));
                    String sCurrentLine;
                    while ((sCurrentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            int dDate = Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine);
                            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
                            Date date = new Date();
                            int iDate = Integer.parseInt(dateFormat.format(date));
                            if (dDate < iDate) {
                                sCurrentLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
                                DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
                                listModel.addElement(sCurrentLine);
                            }
                            else {
                                sCurrentLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
                            }


                            bufferedReader.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

I am pretty new, but what I am trying to do is get it to read the dat from a line in a text file, then depending on whether or not it is before or after the date sort it, but I dont know if that is the problem, because it just wont write to the jList.

Thanks in advance

Comment: And *where is the question*? Don't think that we will compile your code, fix all issues, and tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: Instead of a code dump of everything you're working on (file manipulation), how about a short snippet of the part of the code that you need help with (JList)?

Comment: what is the question?what are you trying to achieve? what error are you getting?

Comment: did you try running it and post the sample contents of the file

Comment: Im not getting errors. It simply will not add to the jList. and I don't know which part of this is wrong.

Comment: *"It simply will not add to the jList."*  Try it with hard-coded strings first.

Comment: You should allocate `DefaultListModel` once, fill it and then set it to a `JList`. In your case you do allocate it on every new line you read.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I did. Like 5 times, didn't work. =(

Comment: I think the problem is with these code _Date date = new Date();
                            int iDate = Integer.parseInt(dateFormat.format(date));_ the date object has null value

Comment: Really? Its not that hard to understand this "rubbish" code. whatever. Ill figure it out myself.

Comment: *"Its not that hard to understand this .. code."*  My words were poorly chosen.  Please try reading it again in 10 minutes without the extraneous addition.  E.G. *"Post that code instead of code snippets involving the file-system and readers."*

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to save your data in `listModel` ? If so, then you should try declaring and initializing `listModel` before you begin your loop. And then, inside the loop, you just keep adding the data to the `listModel` that has already been created.

```
if (dDate < iDate) {
    sCurrentLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
    DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    listModel.addElement(sCurrentLine);
}
```

Because of `DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();` you have a new listModel created in every instance of your loop.

Comment: experience is the biggest teacher..i guess.. :)